# Annotating matplotlib heatmap

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I created a simple heatmap on Matplotlib on a already existing image, now i'm trying to show the values on the cells, but the problem is that the values won't go inside the heatmap, but all around the image, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpdEp.png) is a screenshot.

I think this happens because i'm generating the heatmap on top of an image, but i don't know how to fix that. Here is my code:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

ax.imshow(im)

a = [[0.0233188  0.0232844  0.0233099  0.0242786 ]
     [0.0233158  0.023217   0.02370096 0.02434176]
     [0.02328474 0.02319508 0.02433976 0.02290478]
     [0.02320107 0.02345002 0.02484117 0.02355316]
     [0.02317872 0.02374418 0.02374605 0.02157998]]

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

bounds1 = sorted([0.023,  np.amin(a), np.amax(a)])
norm1 = matplotlib.colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vcenter=bounds1[1], vmin=bounds1[0], vmax=bounds1[2])

Map = ax1.imshow(a, interpolation='none', norm=norm1, extent=[0, 1.15, 0, 0.85])

x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in range(len(y1)):
    for j in range(len(x1)):
        text = ax1.text(j, i, a[i, j],
                       ha="center", va="center", color="r")
```

Comment: Could it be that it's due to the `extend` kwarg in the second `imshow`? Using this means that you heatmap is now located between these values and not between 1 and 5. Could you try to use values for x1 and y1 that are inside your extend?

Comment: Please post the full version of your code. `ax.imshow(im)` what is `im` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extent=[x0, x1, y0, y1]` changes the x and y coordinates of the image.  When there are N cells between x0 and x1, the cell centers can be found by splitting the distance into `2N+1` parts and taking the 1st<sup>, 3</sup>rd<sup>, 5</sup>th, ... position of that list.

Note that as `imshow(a, ...)` didn't use `origin='lower'`, the values are reversed. So, for the y-positions need to be traversed in reverse order.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('off')

a = np.array([[0.0233188, 0.0232844, 0.0233099, 0.0242786],
              [0.0233158, 0.023217, 0.02370096, 0.02434176],
              [0.02328474, 0.02319508, 0.02433976, 0.02290478],
              [0.02320107, 0.02345002, 0.02484117, 0.02355316],
              [0.02317872, 0.02374418, 0.02374605, 0.02157998]])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

bounds1 = sorted([0.023, np.amin(a), np.amax(a)])
norm1 = matplotlib.colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vcenter=bounds1[1], vmin=bounds1[0], vmax=bounds1[2])

x0, x1, y0, y1 = 0, 1.15, 0, 0.85
Map = ax1.imshow(a, interpolation='none', norm=norm1, extent=[x0, x1, y0, y1])

for i, yi in enumerate(np.linspace(y0, y1, 2 * a.shape[0] + 1)[-2::-2]):
    for j, xj in enumerate(np.linspace(x0, x1, 2 * a.shape[1] + 1)[1::2]):
        text = ax1.text(xj, yi, f'{a[i, j]:.6f}',
                        ha="center", va="center", color='darkred' if a[i, j] > bounds1[1] else 'white', fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]